# "a" or "an" before MoU

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

I have a doubt regarding the rules to use article "an" before words with vowel sound.

As per the rules, we should use "an" before MoU, but I have seen "a" before it at some places.

For instance,
*PCB had sought a huge amount from BCCI for not honouring a MoU signed between the two boards. (dnaindia.com)*

Please let me know the correct usage.

Comment: It depends entirely on how you pronounce it. If you pronounce the first syllable as "em", then you use "an". If you pronounce the first syllable with the consonant sound [m] at the start (for example, if you pronounce it as "memorandum of understanding"), then you use "a".

Comment: sumelic is exactly right. And because of that you get to give  a little hint as to how you would like it pronounced by choosing to write it with “a” or “an”.

Comment: If someone pronounces it as "Memorandum of Understanding", I'd expect then to write "Memorandum of Understanding" as well, rather than "MoU"!

Comment: @MrLister exactly

Comment: @sumelic You would also use 'a' if you treated it as an acronym and pronounced it "moo".  For example "An MIT masters degree" but "A NATO defence force".